# Meteor method return value

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I was running a Meteor app locally using auto-publish and now I want to deploy it, so i've removed auto-publish and started using methods. But I'm having a problem. One of my template helpers was directly returning a MongoDB search, and now with the Meteor.call() is returning undefined. How can i fix this?

The helper (The Mongo seach that i was using is commented):

```
function piadasTemplate.piadas.helpers({
piadas: function () {
    //return Piadas.find({}, {sort: {data: -1}});
    return Meteor.call("piadas");
}
```

The method:

```
Meteor.methods({
piadas : function() {
    return Piadas.find({}, {sort: {data: -1}});
}
```

Comment: The line you've commented out in your helper is correct - but you need to *subscribe* to this data, not return it from a method. See the tutorial on publish/subscribe: https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/publish-and-subscribe

Comment: Have you tried fetching the cursor as `return Piadas.find({}, {sort: {data: -1}}).fetch();`?

Comment: @chridam It didnt worked.

Comment: @rubie You mean this? 

    Meteor.startup(function() {
   
    Meteor.subscribe("piadas");
    
});

I got this in my index.js

Comment: @EduardoFantini That's the *subscription*, you also need a corresponding *publication* on the server - `Meteor.publish("piadas", function(){return Piadas.find()})` and then your commented out helper will give you what you want - the method call is incorrect. Just follow the part of the tutorial I linked to and it should all make sense.

Comment: @rubie I'm not getting it, can you explain it to me?

Comment: @EduardoFantini this is a good site to help you understand meteor - and the publish/subscribe explanation is quite good: http://www.meteor-tuts.com/chapters/1/pubsub.html